# VBA - error 53: file not found, there is a non-latin character in filename

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to add defined folder and its subfolders of all levels to collection. It crashes with error mentioned in the title on line `attrVal = GetAttr(path & currentPath)`, when it encounters a file with Danish character "ø". Is there any way I can do operations on files and folders which contain non-latin letters not from my regional settings?

```
Option Explicit

Public OutCollection As New Collection
Public MainPath As String

Sub test()
    Set OutCollection = Nothing       
    MainPath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test folder\"
    TraversePath MainPath
End Sub

Sub TraversePath(path As String)

    Dim currentPath As String
    Dim directory As Variant
    Dim dirCollection As New Collection
    Dim attrVal As Long

    If path = MainPath Then OutCollection.Add path

    currentPath = Dir(path, vbDirectory)

    'current directory
    Do Until currentPath = vbNullString
        If Left(currentPath, 1) <> "." Then
            attrVal = GetAttr(path & currentPath)
            Select Case attrVal
            Case 16, 48 'folder or folder marked for backup or removal
                dirCollection.Add currentPath
                OutCollection.Add path & currentPath
            End Select
        End If
        currentPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'subsequent directories
    For Each directory In dirCollection
        TraversePath path & directory & "\"
    Next directory

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try if the FSO can work with non-latin characters:

```
Public Function GetFileInfo(ByVal sFile As String)
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim fso                   As Object
    Dim f                     As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.GetFile(sFile)

    Debug.Print f.Name               
    Debug.Print , "Size: " & f.Size  
    Debug.Print , "Created: " & f.DateCreated
    Debug.Print , "Modified: " & f.DateLastModified
    Debug.Print , "Accessed: " & f.DateLastAccessed
    Debug.Print , "Type: " & f.Type
    Debug.Print , "Attributes: " & f.Attributes

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set f = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error " & Err.Number, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

Have a look at [Attributes Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/5tx15443%28v%3Dvs.84%29) to see which values for `.Attributes` are returned.

Comment: This is perfect, with FSO I can operate on non-latin character folder and file names. I can also check whether an item in Shell Folder object is a file by using `FSO.getfile(objShellFile.path)` with error handling. I needed it because another way to check if an item is a file is to use `GetAttr(ObjShellFile.path)` function which crashes on non-latin chars.