# Excel VBA non-english character support for reading files

Tags: excel, vba, utf-8, character-encoding, non-english

I am using this piece of code for seperating sheets to single files:

```
Sub Splitbook()
Dim xPath As String
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
   xWs.Copy
   Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
   Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But I get these two errors respectively when I run the code:
[image]
[image]

and that file *".\VB5052.tmp"* is being created at run time.
I figured out that this error occurs when my path have non-english characters. So, how to configure VBA in order to support non-english characters?

By the way, I have many different paths and I am doing this seperation most times.

This Path didn't work: **"D:\Yeni Klasör"**
However, when I remove the **"ö"** character: **"D:\Yeni"** this works. My sheet names include non-english characters but it is not the error. Just editing the path works.

Comment: Maybe the issue is at the OS level, what kind of special characters have you?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add sample sheet names  pasted as text (not image please).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341330/vba-error-53-file-not-found-there-is-a-non-latin-character-in-filename ?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: I bet it is not the `ö` that causes the issue but the space in the path. Try to enclose your path in double quotes `""` like `Filename:="""" & xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"""`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I tried your code and it doesn't work. The problem is the "ö" character.

Comment: Well I can use `ö` in a path without issues. To proof that the `ö` is actually the issue here please try to save in `D:\Yeni Klasor` wher just the `ö` gets changed in the path but *nothing else* (I know you tried `D:\Yeni` but that removed also the space not only the `ö`). What happens?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ "D:\Yeni Klasor" without "ö" worked perfectly with the code in the question

Comment: By the way, same issue exists on Javascript. I found the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831465/arabic-characters-doesnt-show-properly-in-javascript/38831540#38831540) for javascript. I think the problem lies on the locale of the OS.

Comment: @MichalRosa can you show me how can I use FSO in my code?

Comment: @ninbit Well yes must have something to do with the localization of your OS (and/or Excel). I'm on a german Windows with german Excel, and `ö` is a common german character. So using `Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Temp\Yeni Klasör\test.xlsm"` works out of the box for me without issues. So maybe you should include some information about your OS locale in your question ([edit]). • You cannot use `FSO` so save a file.

Comment: That sentence "I'm on a german Windows with german Excel, and ö is a common german character" solved the problem. I remember I changed the localization to Arabic and left it off. Now I changed it to Turkish and works perfectly. So post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is just controlling the system locale on windows like that:

1. Go to Control Panel,
2. Click Clock, Language and Region
3. Windows 10, Windows 8: Click Region
   Windows 7: Click Region and Language
   Windows XP: Click Regional and Language Options
   The Region and Language options dialog appears.
4. Click the Administrative tab
   On Windows XP, click the Advanced tab
   If there is no Advanced tab, then you are not logged in with administrative privileges.
5. Under the Language for non-Unicode programs section, click Change system locale and select the desired language.
6. Click OK
7. Restart the computer to apply the change.

In the 5th step, choose the language that you need (i.e. the language that has your character). Otherwise your path will contain some different characters which cause errors at run time.